# font-awesome icons not showing up in Chrome 61

Tags: google-chrome, font-awesome, stylesheet

I've downloaded font-awesome icons in my project and imported `font-awesome.min.css` as

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

And used them simply like

```
<i class="fa fa-user-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

- The stylesheet was loaded so there was no problem with the path.
- The icons worked fine in Firefox, but didn't show up in Chrome 61 at all,  neither in Win 10 nor Linux, so I guess it has nothing to do with OS.
- I don't have any plugin in Chrome that would be conflicting.
- I've also tried `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">` but nothing changed.

Does anyone know what might cause this problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forgot to mention, I'm using Polymer. And here is a solution I found.

1. install `polymer-font-awesome` with npm:

   `npm i polymer-font-awesome`
2. add the following dependency to `polymer.json`:

   `"extraDependencies": ["node_modules/polymer-font-awesome/dist/fonts/*"]`
3. import these two files:

   `<link rel="import" href="node_modules/polymer-font-awesome/dist/font-face.html">`
   `<link rel="import" href="node_modules/polymer-font-awesome/dist/font-awesome.html">`
4. include stlye module:

   `<style type="text/css" include="font-awesome"></style>`

Clear the cache in Chrome and it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having this exact same issue. I tried re-downloading the fonts and the css, rewriting my css into a new file, removing some of the scripts and tags in the head tag and nothing works. It seems to be related to Chrome 61. I was going to report this to the FA's github, but it looks like someone [already did](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/issues/11722).

Comment: I believe it has something to do with Chrome 61, too. I also reported an issue in FA's github, but it seems they haven't taken this problem seriously yet.

Comment: @YuKitAs thats really unfortunate.... I really like FA, its easy to use and looks really nice. I hope theres a fix soon. One thing I did notice is some of the bootstrap templates _do_ work. Check this one out here, does it work on Chrome for you? https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-freelancer

Comment: That works for me on Chrome. But like I said in the other answer, now I'm using polymer-font-awesome instead :)

Comment: Oh sweet, thanks for the tip. Guess I'll be switching over as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you have any kind of AdBlock turned on, you need to disable it first.
I also have the same problem that font-awesome icons appear in Firefox but not in Chrome, and I figured out that my Chrome AdBlock blocked it.

Comment: I already heard about that, but I don't have it installed in my Chrome. And I think it only blocks some parts of the icons, like brand icons. Thanks for the reply anyway.